# Print the IP address of a printer through a USB connection

Tags: windows, networking, printer

I am connected to a network printer with a USB cable. Is there anyway to make this printer print its IP address?

The printer is an HP LaserJet P2015.

Comment: This is very dependent on your particular printer.  Please edit your question with the specific model of printer you have.

Comment: @heavyd I updated it with the model, although I was hoping there would be a general method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the manual for your specific printer on the [HP website](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/manualsResults/?lang=en&cc=us&sp4ts.oid=1845551).

Here is an excerpt from the manual:

> The Configuration page lists current settings and properties of the
> printer. It also contains a status log report. You can print a
> Configuration page from the following locations:
>
> ● Printer control panel. Press the Go button for five seconds when the printer Ready
> light is on and no other jobs are printing.
>
> ● Embedded Web server
>
> ● HP ToolboxFX
>
> ...
>
> The Network Configuration page automatically prints when you print a Configuration page from the control panel. The Network Configuration page provides the following information about the printer network configuration:
>
> ● IP address
>
> ● firmware version
>
> ● network statistics
>
> ● protocol information

Comment: Pressing the Go button for 5 seconds printed all three pages listed on the website.

Answer (score 1):

On most printers, printing a test page should give you all the information about that printer. That includes its IP address if it's connected to the network.

Comment: Unfortunately the test page does not include an IP address. The closest thing is `Port name(s): USB001`.

Answer (score 1):

If your device isn't connected to a network port, it will not print an IP address because it never received one.

If it's printing all available connections on it's configuration page and it only displays USB connections it's likely not even connected to a network cable.

Comment: It is connected to the network with a network port. I am connected to it with USB.